# How to display popups inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have some links from remote website [not in my control]. I am trying to display links given by remote website on my personal website. Remote website links contains pop ups.

I want the pop ups to display inside iframe windows. By default they open a popup inside the same windows and close  my personal website.

I am using this code.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" name="popads" width="450" height="450" src="Remote Website"></iframe>
```

Thanks to give solutions for this problem.

Comment: Are the links in question part of the remote content? If so  the content in the iframe probably has links with a target="_blank" attribute or uses js window.open to handle links. There is nothing you can do about that. The content in an iframe is not part of your document and can not be manipulated.

Comment: Those links are from ptp[ paid to promote] websites. that displays popups ... I just want to restrict pop up inside their native iframe.

Comment: This seems to me you are doing some really not-helpful stuff to the internet, so I tend not to answer such question. I would be happy if you explain what you are trying to achieve here and hear that it is not about making money out of ad-networks.

Comment: @rubo77 , If you can make money using legal ways of technology. whats wrong in that. Yes I am trying to place a ptp website that open its ads inside the frame... I would appreciate if you can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery Dialog. Its simple and clean.
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add some piece of code what you are trying to do .....

Comment: I am trying to display 3 to 4 remote website , that are PTP sites and they automatically , open the popups when the pages loads,, I want to places those links inside iframe and want those links to open popups inside their iframes.
I have already uploaded the code that i am using .. nothing more code i am using there

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done this way.

You cannot alter the way another website works. This would be called "cross-site-scripting"

You would have to download those sites to your webserver (for example with PHP), alter the code and then deliver them as yours FROM YOUR SERVER.

Then you can include those altered sites in your iframes.

(There are also online services for altering webpages, for example "Yahoo pipes")

Comment: I am not trying to alter any thing , I am just trying to keep popups inside the iframe.. dont want them to open a new windows. I guess this should be achievable task..

Comment: It is not possible. The only way would be scraping the pages without the pop-up code